# How to write a sharp (#) or hash-tag in Lilypond markup

Tags: lilypond

I want to write a Cis (C-sharp) with `markup{}`.

I am aware that there is a difference between the usual hashtag sign `#` (used in commenting code or on twitter) and the muscial sharp sign `♯`.

With the original sharp sign this code works well.

```
markup{C♯}
```

But I found out that it does not work with a hashtag even if it is escaped

```
markup{C#}
markup{C\#}
```

So why is that and how could this be solved without the original sharp sign?

Comment: Because # is LilyPond syntax to introduce Scheme code. Try \markup { "C#" }.

Comment: Why don't you just set up a keyboard layout that can type a ♯ rather than all this messing around? macOS you could do it with Ukelele [or even just a text replacement as I used here]. I'm sure Windows must have some sort of equivalent, even if it's the lumpy alt/unicode thing.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `#` is more usually known as the ‘hash’ sign*;  hash_tag_ is the metadata tag _beginning_ with a hash symbol. (* It's also sometimes called the ‘number’ sign — and in the US ‘pound’ sign, referring to the weight unit, but that's confusing in e.g. the UK where the pound sign is `£` referring to the currency.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:
`\markup{C\sharp}`

You might also like to make the symbol smaller and raise it up with `\super`, and and you'll probably want to concatenate the letter and symbol together with `\concat`; something like:

`\markup{\concat{C\super\sharp}}`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what you want.  You write

> I am aware that there is a difference between the usual hashtag sign # (used in commenting code or on twitter) and the muscial sharp sign ♯.

And you state

> With the original sharp sign this code works well.
> `\markup{C♯}`

Yet you appear to desire getting a hashtag sign instead of an accidental in a musical context.  That makes little enough sense.  Of course, LilyPond uses the hashtag sign for something different (introducing Scheme), and "it does not work with a hashtag even if it is escaped" is nonsensical in a language that does not use backslashes to escape special characters (other than in very specific in-string contexts).

It appears that you want `\markup "C#"` or in most contexts the simpler `"C#"` though it is unclear why.

Comment: What makes you say "you appear to desire getting a hashtag sign instead of an accidental"?